# Tap Gesture not working as expected when added to uiview in collectionview cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am adding a tap gesture recognizer programmatically to a custom collection view cell class. for some reason, it doesnt seem to be working. the frame is not 0, isUserInteractionEnabled is set to true and i made sure the tap view is on top of all other views:

The custom cell class:

```
let containerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let tapView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return v
}()

let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = {
    let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
    return t
}()

@objc fileprivate func tapped() {
    print("tap")
}

func setTap() {
    self.containerView.addSubview(tapView)
    tapView.frame = self.frame
    // layout constraint code - printing frame shows its not 0 after this

    tapView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

In the view controller file that has the collection view:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SuggestCell
    cell.category.text = data[indexPath.row].category
    cell.word.text = data[indexPath.row].word
    cell.setTap()
    print(cell.tapView.frame)
    return cell
}
```

I do realize that there is a didSelectItemAt method but I am trying some custom behavior that detects multiple taps to a cell and performs an action

Comment: did you add containerView to your cell's contentView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that in your definition of `tap` property, `self` is not the instance of the custom cell class because at the time the property is created, the object hasn't been fully initialized.

If you add:

```
print(type(of: self))
```

to that code, you will see that it prints:

```
(CustomCell) -> () -> CustomCell
```

instead of the desired:

```
CustomCell
```

So your target/action is using the wrong target.

An easy way to fix this is to make `tap` a `lazy var`:

```
lazy var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = {
    let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
    return t
}()
```

Then, the first time you access `tap`, the tap gesture recognizer will be created and at that time, your custom cell will be created and `self` will refer to the instance of the class.

---

Alternatively, you can make `tap` a *computed property*:

```
var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
    return t
}
```

and `tap` will create and return a `UITapGestureRecognizer` when it is accessed.  Again, in that case, the custom cell will be created, so `self` will properly refer to the instance of the class.

Comment: THANK YOU GUY FIERI! lol i appreciate the detailed answer. lesson learned!